# SQL syntax query error

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the problem with this query?:

```
SELECT
    'posts'.'post_id' AS 'id',
    'posts'.'post_title' AS 'title',
    LEFT('posts','post_body', 512) AS 'preview',
    'posts'.'post_user' AS 'user',
    DATE_FORMAT('posts'.'post_date', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'DATE',
    'comments'.'total_comments',
    DATE_FORMAT('comments'.'last_comment', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'last_comment'
    FROM 'posts'
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
        'post_id',
        COUNT('comment_id') AS 'total_comments',
        MAX('comment_date') AS 'last_comment'
        FROM 'comments'
        GROUP BY 'post_id'
    ) AS 'comments'
    ON 'posts'.'post_id' = 'comments'.'post_id'
    ORDER BY 'posts'.'post_date' DESC
```

I get:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.'post_id' AS 'id', 'posts'.'post_title' AS 'title', LEFT('posts','p' at line 2

Comment: Since you are using MySQL use the backticks not single quotes around tables, columns and aliases.

Comment: This is a so-called PICNIC error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use normal apostrophes ("'"), but backticks "`" in MYSQL. Normal apostrophes are used to quote strings. Please also note that I changed the comma in

```
LEFT(`posts`,`post_body`, 512) as `preview`
```

to a period.

It should read:

```
SELECT
        `posts`.`post_id` AS `id`,
        `posts`.`post_title` AS `title`,
        LEFT(`posts`.`post_body`, 512) AS `preview`,
        `posts`.`post_user` AS `user`,
        DATE_FORMAT(`posts`.`post_date`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS `DATE`,
        `comments`.`total_comments`,
        DATE_FORMAT(`comments`.`last_comment`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS `last_comment`
        FROM `posts`
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                `post_id`,
                COUNT(`comment_id`) AS `total_comments`,
                MAX(`comment_date`) AS `last_comment`
                FROM `comments`
                GROUP BY `post_id`
                ) AS `comments`
        ON `posts`.`post_id` = `comments`.`post_id`
        ORDER BY `posts`.`post_date` DESC
```

Comment: thanks, but i get #1054 - Unknown column 'posts.post_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Well, is there a `post_id` column in your table?

Answer (score 4):

You're using a string literal as a table:

```
FROM 'posts'
```

If you'd like to escape the table name, use backticks, like:

```
FROM `posts`
```

Escaping a table name is not required; `from posts` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your LEFT syntax is wrong, change the first comma to a period

```
LEFT('posts','post_body', 512) AS 'preview',
```

should be

```
LEFT('posts'.'post_body', 512) AS 'preview',
```